# Error:Data error (cyclic redundancy check)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Unable to build the project and getting following errors...

**Messages**

[image]

**Event Log**

[image]

**Project level build.gradle file**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
}
```

**Version Information**

- Android Studio 2.2.1
- compileSdkVersion 24
- buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
- OS Windows 7 64 Bit

**Gradle Settings**

[image]

I've tried a lot of things but in the end, I have to asked it here. Please help.

Comment: I have the same problem, Try This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68574779/1931811) hope it help

Comment: After 5 years..! I have even changed my domain from mobility to cloud! Will give it a try whenever possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try to `clean project`

1. Go to `Build`
2. Click the `clean project` button
3. Wait for the build to finish

Answer (score 1):

You can fix that error by using these steps

- open cmd (as administrator)
- `chkdsk D:/f/r`
- restart

Comment: I've reset everything, because it's my office pc & could not wait. Well thanks. It will be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a low-level software/hardware issue.**

The "Data Error (Cyclic redundancy check)" errors appears when programs try to read from bad sectors on your storage drive. There are two types of bad sectors – *logical* and *physical*.

***Logical*** bad sectors are easy to repair: go to **This PC**, then right-click click the drive where your project is stored and click **Properties**. In the **Properties** window, go to the **Tools** tab and under **Error Checking** click **Check** and then **Scan this drive**. Windows will check the drive for errors – logical bad sectors.

***Physical*** bad sectors are a real pain and there is no way to get rid of them other than to **replace the drive**. Physical bad sectors are common to HHD drives and are a *result of physical damage* to the drive.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the file where the error giving..
before deleteing the file don't forget to copy the code to notepad.

Then recreate the file again and paste the code from notepad.Then sync the project again. Boom the error will be gone.

After 5 years of posting problem it has no solution.  So i decided to post a solution if anyone got this error. I have faced this problems 2 times.  But don't know why