# Android Studio Error:Data error cyclic redundancy check

Tags: android, android-studio-3.1

I was working on a Project and this required me to reinstall the latest version of Android Studio. After the Installation when I opened the Project I,m getting this error.
I have tried the single answer available, but it won't work. I am using te latest version of Android Studio (3.1.1).

"ERROR: Data error (cyclic redundancy check)"

[image]

Comment: Meaning that first module depends on second module and second module has dependency on first module. **A => B B=> A.** Check your **dependencies** in **build.gradle** files and check also this article, may help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513827/how-to-solve-circular-dependency-in-gradle-multi-project-build

Comment: I did not created a new project.I uninstalled the previous version of android studio, deleted all the folder except SDK and then Installed the new one and opened my project in it.

Comment: Ok, understand, try to clean/ rebuild project. If that does not help try also invalidate/cache restart.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431953/could-not-read-entry-from-cache-taskartifacts-bin/38431974

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and the problem was that there was a **corrupted file** its name appear to me in android studio, that file android studio can't read as there was a bad sector in its hard location

**Solution** for me was to copy file content from android studio and create new one with the same in its location , hope it help others,

Comment: I've the same problem and did this solution for a long time but now it doesn't work anyway

Answer (score 0):

In my case there is problem with gradle version cached in PC.

I solved this problem by just removing the `{home}\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-8.2-bin` file and then sync project again.